# How to keep 3 numbers after decimal and zeros in JS

Tags: javascript

Here i have faced a problem, its not a typical question and i have not found much solutions on internet about it.
If i want to keep 2 or 3 decimal places its okay, there is much solutions.
But if i have a number like this? `0.000010255258583418511` and i want to keep `0.00000103` from it?
Or if i have a number like this `0.00003135110744878017` and i want to keep `0.00000313` from it?
I mean i want to keep non zero numbers after decimal point up-to 3 or 4 points.
How can i approach to solve it?

Comment: In suggested related questions below there are answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/how-to-round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-if-necessary

Answer (score 0):

```
let num = 1.23456789
num = Number(num.toFixed(3))
console.log(num) // 1.235
```